# Extracted images from PDF using iTextsharp not in correct format - C#

Tags: itext

I am using iTextsharp to extract images from the PDF file, i am able to extract images but the extracted images are not in correct format (i.e. it looks like negative proof).

[image]

Code:

```
string sFilePath = "Test3.pdf";
int pageNum = 1;

PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(sFilePath);

PdfDictionary pg = pdf.GetPageN(pageNum);
PdfDictionary res = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pg.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES));
PdfDictionary xobj = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT));
if (xobj == null) { return; }
int imageCount = 0;
foreach (PdfName name in xobj.Keys)
{
    PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(name);
    if (!obj.IsIndirect()) { continue; }
    PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
    PdfName type = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
    if (!type.Equals(PdfName.IMAGE)) { continue; }
    int XrefIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((PRIndirectReference)obj).Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    PdfObject pdfObj = pdf.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex);
    PdfStream pdfStrem = (PdfStream)pdfObj;
    byte[] bytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)pdfStrem);
    if (bytes == null) { continue; }
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        try
        {
            memStream.Position = 0;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream);

            if (!Directory.Exists(imgPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imgPath);

            string path = Path.Combine(imgPath, String.Format(@"{0}.jpg", ++imageCount));
            System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters parms = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
            parms.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 0);
            var jpegEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList().Find(x => x.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
            img.Save(path, jpegEncoder, parms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code, we are not fortune-tellers :)

Comment: Is there a special reason why you do not use iTextSharp's image extraction capabilities in the `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.*` classes but instead try to re-invent that? Furthermore, your code does not take mask information into account.

Comment: Thx mkl, no specific reason, when i searched i got this code so i have used the same for verifying , the same code working fine for other PDF files. Can you descriobe in detail abt my mistake. plz advice on this. thx in advance.

Comment: *Can you descriobe in detail abt my mistake.* — The mistake in your code is that you only consider the subtype of the stream object and its stream content but ignore all other attributes the stream may have. The parser classes mentioned above consider more of the attributes and, therefore, are more successful extracting different kinds of images. Furthermore some of the images you find actually might well be image masks instead of finished images. You might want to study section 8.9 of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: See this thread, too: http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg54543.html